# loading data in datatable on onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I want to implement function in which data will be loaded into datatable after onChange event. So for that I am trying to implement code as below.

```
var viewdatatab  =  $('#dataTablesFeedback').dataTable({                    

                "columns": [

                    { "data": "resourceId" },
                    { "data": "feedbackRecommendation" },
                    { "data": "technicalSkillGaps" },
                    { "data": "technicalAvgSkills" },
                    { "data": "feedbackType" },
                    { "data": "feedbackId" },
                    { "data": "isNew" },

                ]
        });
```

Which is creating my datatable layout and I am calling below function on dropdown change event is :

```
function loadFeedback(){

viewdatatabJS  =    $('#dataTablesFeedback').dataTable({                    
     "processing" : true,
     "retrieve" : true,
    "ajax" : "/nhp/rest/feedback/viewFeedback",
    "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
       aoData.push( { "name": "userName", "value":employeeId } ,
                    { "name": "resourceId", "value":mentorDataJson[$('#dropDownId').val()].resourceId });
     }, 
});
}
```

Where I am passing some parameter in aoData.push but my URL is not getting called.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code using a debugger to see where it's going wrong? Have you read the Bootstrap documentation to make sure you're using the `.dataTable` function correctly? Are there any error messages being generated?

Where and how is your `loadFeedback` function being called?

Comment: @amphetamachine : yes i tried to debug the code but it is not hitting the url from client end only and also not giving any error in firebug. i am calling my loadFeedback function from my jsp page where i have written this function on "onChange" event of drop down box selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved the issue by simply implementing datatable properties. i wrote my code of datatable

```
      var viewdatatab  =  $('#dataTablesFeedback').dataTable({                    

            "columns": [

                { "data": "resourceId" },
                { "data": "feedbackRecommendation" },
                { "data": "technicalSkillGaps" },
                { "data": "technicalAvgSkills" },
                { "data": "feedbackType" },
                { "data": "feedbackId" },
                { "data": "isNew" },

            ]
    });
```

in jsp document.ready(function()) and then on my request call of drop down change event i wrote below code on my javascript function.

```
      $.ajax({
      url : "",
      type: 'GET',
      contentType: "application/json",
      data:  {
            'userName': value,
            'resourceId' : value,
         },
           success: function(data) {
            var table = $('#dataTablesFeedback').DataTable();
            table.clear();
            table.rows.add(data.data);
            table.draw();     
         });
```

this way i first clear my datatable and then redraw it using my json which i got from my ajax call.
Thanks

Comment: This is wrong. Re-initializing table will throw error. $('#dataTablesFeedback').DataTable();